# Python 3 hangman for a beginner

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to hangman. Are you ready to have some fun?")

def play():
 import random
 List = ["random", "words", "list"]

 word = str(random.choice(List))
 mistake = 7
 alreadySaid = set()
 board = "_" * len(word)

 print(" ".join(board))
 while mistake > 0:
     while True:
         guess = input("Please guess a letter: ")
         if len(guess) <= 1:
             break
         else:
             print("Too long. Enter only one letter.")
     if guess in word:
         alreadySaid.add(guess)
         print("Correct!",guess, " was in the word!")
         board = "".join([guess if guess in word else "_" for str in word])
         if board == word:
             print("Congratulations! You´re correct!!!")
     elif guess not in word:
         mistake -= 1
         print("Wrong!", mistake," mistakes remaining.")
         if mistake <= 0:
            print("Game Over")
      print(" ".join(board))

play()
```

I'm trying to make hangman with python 3 but whenever I input a correct letter it comes out as a word of only that letter. For example for random when I input r the output is r r r r r r when I want r _ _ _ _ _. What do you think is wrong? Also do I have any other problems?

Comment: Try changing `guess if guess in word` to `str if str in alreadySaid`.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest you take a step back and try a different, cleaner approach? Besides that, I suggest you keep your hidden word as a list, since strings are immutable and do not support item assignment, which means you cannot reveal the character if the user's guess was correct (you can then `join()` it when you need it to display it to the user as a string):

```
import random

word_list = [
    'spam',
    'eggs',
    'foo',
    'bar'
]

word = random.choice(word_list)

guess = ['_'] * len(word)
chances = 7

while '_' in guess and chances > 0:

    print(' '.join(guess))

    char = input('Enter char: ')

    if len(char) > 1:
        print('Please enter only one char.')
        continue

    if char not in word:
        chances -= 1

        if chances == 0:
            print('Game over!')
            break
        else:
            print('You have', chances, 'chances left.')
    else:
        for i, x in enumerate(word):
            if x == char:
                guess[i] = char
else:
    print(''.join(guess))
    print('Congratulations!')
```